# ActiveMQ DiscoveryAgent

Tags: activemq-classic

I try to implement another DiscoveryAgent using a kind of database. I find this code and it helps me to understand how the DiscoveryAgent works :
https://github.com/sliard/multicastdb

But I don't know when the method registerService is called. When I changed the code of the multicast DiscoveryAgent to see when it's called, but it isn't when the DiscoveryAgent starts. But if it's not called, the broker can't advertize itself to the database...
Then I don't understand how a broker can communicate with another using the information of a DiscoveryAgent.

So if you can explain me when this method is called and if you have some documentation on the implementation of a DiscoveryAgent, it would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The registerService method is called from the Broker's TransportConnector when it is started which is at a different time from the start of the agent.  You should take some time to look at the code of the various agents in ActiveMQ.  The multicast version and the HTTP agent are good examples.

Keep in mind that the agents are written for both the Broker and the Client code to use so there is some code that isn't run from the Broker side and some that's not used on the client end.  If you want to implement only a client side agent then you don't need to worry about the registration or advertisement bits, but if you want the broker to add itself to your DB implementation you would want to implement those bits so that the broker can add itself and do whatever your advertisement mechanism is.

The source code and test are your best documentation.  Look at the code, run the tests and set breakpoints to see what's going on.  You can even build from source and add in your own Logging if need be to get a better feel for it.